# Como podria escribir esto sin que me arrojara un error de sintaxis?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando calcular números en un rango que al ser divididos entre 2 3 4 5 y 6, den resto 1 2 3 4 y 5, respectivamente. El error de síntaxis se encuentra al intentar usar el módulo e igualarlo a el resto que quiero obtener.

```
n = 0

while n < 439:

    if n%2=1 and n%3=2 and n%4=3 and n%5=4 and n%6=5
        print (n)
    else:
        n += 1
```

El error de síntaxis se encuentra al intentar hacer **n%2=1**

Comment: El problema es que te falta terminar el `if` con `:` dos puntos. Asi es la sintaxis de python para poder tomar un bloque tabulado.

Comment: Oh, no me había fijado. De todas formas el intérprete de python, al corregir el error me lanza un error de síntaxis cuando intento igualar el símbolo de módulo (%) a un número, para discriminar a los números que no tengan el resto deseado. Gracias por responder!

Comment: Ademaś de lo que comenta Andrespenginner debes usar `==` (operador de igualdad) no `=` (asignación), es decir `n % 2 == 1`

Comment: Claro!, había olvidado que = asigna, y que == funciona como igualdad. Muchas gracias!